# restkit 0.20: can not pass in an NSManagedObject to the getObject: method

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am simply trying to retrieve one item from my restful service (confirmed working)

```
http://www.example.com/person/25
```

I need to somehow pass in the '25' part of the URL.  I figure that I'm supposed to use RKRoute.  The way to execute this in RestKit is to use the getObject: method of RKObjectManager.

Using RestKit 0.22 and I do not know how to call the getObject: method because it expects a full Person object, no?  Even though I only need to pass in the string '25'.

The method in question is:     `[self getObject:personNSManagedObject path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) .....`

I can't just say "Person *person = [[Person alloc] init] because Person is an NSManagedObject.

But when I do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *person = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
Person *personNSManObj = [[Person alloc] initWithEntity:person insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
personNSManObj.id = 3;
```

I get the following error:

> Performing object mapping to temporary target objectID. Results may
>   not be accessible without obtaining a permanent object ID. 
>   restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:457 Failed to retrieve
>   existing object with ID: 0x1664ac90

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should save the new object back to the persistent store. The data load and mapping is happening on a different thread but will try to map data back into the supplied object. Because the object is inserted but not saved it has a temporary managed object id which RestKit tries to convert into an object but can't. Saving will create a 'stub' object in the data store which RestKit will fully populate with the response data (assuming success).

An alternative approach is to supply a dictionary with the required key / value pair which will be inserted into the route. RestKit will then create the destination object for you.

Comment: Hi Wain, wow thanks alot for this help.  I'm thinking about going the dictionary route.  Can you give me a hint as to in which class I would supply this dictionary?  I don't see a parameter that accepts an NSDictionary in the RKRoute documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: A route matches against a supplied class, so you currently match against the managed object class but you can change that to dictionary (or other custom object)'

Comment: @user798719 Can you accept this as the correct answer?